# Interpretation of $L_2 ([-\pi , \pi])$

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

What is the interpretation of $L_2 ([-\pi , \pi])$ in laymans terms?

How is $L_2 ([-\pi , \pi])$ different to $L_1 ([-\pi , \pi])$?

Does $L_2 ([-\pi , \pi])$ just mean that the function is twice integrable in the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x^{\alpha$ is $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ if not. It is in $L^1$ iff $\alpha >-1$, in $L^2$ iff $\alpha >-1/2$. The primitive of a function in $L^2$ is 1/2 Holder.

Comment: $L^2$ means that the square of the function is integrable, whereas $L^1$ means that the absolute value of the function is integrable.

Comment: Note that over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, we have that $L^1$ is larger than $L^2$, while over $(-\infty,\infty)$, it's the other way around.

Comment: @Arthur: On $(-\infty, \infty ) $, neither is larger than the other.

Comment: @PhoemueX you're right, I was too focused on the tail to remember that pathologies may still occur in the middle. They both contain functions that aren't contained in the other.

Comment: @Arthur: You probably had in mind $l^1 \subset l^2$, yes